# How to resolve rate calculation for shipping?

Tags: php

I try to have the save result than this element below to calculate the rate in postcanada.

Do you have an idea to resolve this element because my coe codre return this error

Thank you.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <messages xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/messages"> <message> <code>Server</code> <description>/rs/ship/price: cvc-simple-type 1: element {http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/ship/rate-v3}weight with anonymous type may not be empty</description></message></messages> : 400 in /home/www/clicshopping_test_ui/boutique/ext/api/canadaPost/class.CanadaPost.php on line 176
```

Original code

```
$result = new CanadaPostShipment(
      array(
         'destination' => array('domestic' => array('postal-code' => $origin)),
    'origin-postal-code' => $destination,
    'parcel-characteristics' => array(
      'weight' => round((float)$total_weight, 2), // kg
      'dimensions' => array(
        'width' => round((float)$total_width, 2),
        'length' => round((float)$total_length, 2),
        'height' => round((float)$total_height, 2),
      )
    )
  )
);
```

New code (include some products)

```
  foreach ($products_array as $value) {
    $weight[] = $value['weight'];
    $quantity[] = $value['quantity'];
    $products_dimension_width[] = $value['products_dimension_width'];
    $products_dimension_height[] = $value['products_dimension_height'];
    $products_dimension_depth[] = $value['products_dimension_depth'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($products_array); $i++) {
      $product =  array(
        'destination' => array(
          'domestic' => array(
            'postal-code' => $origin
          )
        ),
        'origin-postal-code' => $destination,
        'parcel-characteristics' => array('weight' => $weight[$i], // kg
                                          'dimensions' => array(
                                                                'width' => $products_dimension_width[$i],
                                                                'length' => $products_dimension_height[$i],
                                                                'height' => $products_dimension_depth[$i],
                                                              )
                                          )
        );

      $result1 = new CanadaPostShipment($product);
      $result[] = $cp->getRates($result1);
    }
  }
```